# How do I pass key/value config settings when submitting a Job to Snappy Job Server?

Tags: spark-jobserver, snappydata

I have a job that loads a data file from a different location each time.  I'd like to submit the same job JAR and just pass a different location to it using the Config.java parameter of the runJavaJob() API.

I do not see a way to pass key/value configuration to the *snappy-job.sh Usage*.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the key value pairs as part of APP_PROPS environment setting before firing the snappy-job.sh. We have demonstrated it in our Getting Started section.

$ export APP_PROPS="consumerKey=,consumerSecret=,accessToken=,accessTokenSecret="

$ ./bin/snappy-job.sh submit --lead localhost:8090 --app-name TwitterPopularTagsJob --class io.snappydata.examples.TwitterPopularTagsJob --app-jar ./lib/quickstart-0.2.1-PREVIEW.jar --stream

Comment: This resolves the current problem - thanks - but it is very dangerous to use an environment variable, which (if not cleared or reset properly) could point to an incorrect value on a later script and lead to bad consequences.  I'd prefer a parameter-based resolution to this.

Comment: Agreed. Will file a JIRA. Thanks.